# How to use typename instead of typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, typename

I have the following code snippet:

```
template <class T>
int foo(T (*f)()) {
    typedef T (*func)();
    typedef functor<T, func> F; //this line 

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, I use `typedef` for a function pointer (`func`), but I want to remove it to simplify my code. I tried this:

```
template <class T>
int foo(T (*f)()) {
    typedef functor<T, typename f> F;

    // ...
}
```

But that doesn't compile. What is the right way to to spell that full `typedef` for `F` in a single line?

Comment: Huh? But `func` is a function pointer type, not a template. What does that line even mean?

Comment: You need `decltype(f)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in the actual type of `f`:

```
typedef functor<T, T(*)()> F;
```

Or you could use `decltype`:

```
typedef functor<T, decltype(f)> F;
```

Or you could write an alias for such a thing:

```
template <typename T>
using ReturnT = T(*)();

template <typename T>
int foo(ReturnT<T> f) {
    using F = functor<T, ReturnT<T>>;
    // ...
}
```